# boost::uuid / unique across different databases

Tags: c++, database, boost, uuid, boost-uuid

I want to generate a uuid which should be used as unique identifier across different systems/databases. I read the examples but i don't understand how i can be sure that the generated id's are unique over different systems and databases.

I hope you can help me out here.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is -- depending on how they are generated -- that there are *so many values* representable with 122-bits* that the chance of *accidental* collisions -- again, depending on how they are generated -- is very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, small.

An excerpt from Wikipedia for the UUID version 4 (Leach-Salz Random):

> In other words, **only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%**. The probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million UUIDs.
>
> ... however, these probabilities only hold when the UUIDs are generated using sufficient entropy.

Of course, there are other UUID generation schemes and "well-known GUIDs", not all of which may be suitable for "globally-unique" usage. (Additionally, non-specialized UUIDs tend not to work well for primary/clustered keys due to fragmentation on insert: SQL Server has [NEWSEQUENTIALID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) to help with that issue.)

Happy coding.

---

*There is a maximum of 128-bits in a UUID, however some UUID versions use some of the bits internally. I do not know what boost uses but I *suspect* it is also UUIDv4.